# Derivative of Incomplete Gamma Function

Tags: derivatives, special-functions, gamma-function

For the following upper incomplete Gamma function:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(1+d,A-c \ln x)=\int_{A-c\ln x}^{\infty}t^{(1+d)-1}e^{-t}dt
\end{equation}
I am trying to calculate the derivative of $Γ$ with respect to $x$. In general it holds that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \Gamma(s,x)=-x^{s-1}e^{-x}
\end{equation}
After my calculations I ended up with:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \Gamma(1+d,A-c \ln x)=c e^{-A}x^{c-1}(A-c\ln x)^d
\end{equation}
but the author says that the correct answer is rather:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \Gamma(1+d,A-c \ln x)=-e^{-A}x^{c-1}(A-c\ln x)^d
\end{equation}
But how is this correct? By applying the chain rule it should be:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \Gamma(1+d,A-c \ln x)=\left[ -(A-c\ln x)^de^{A-c \ln x} \right]\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}(A-c \ln x)
\end{equation}
right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. We have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} Γ(s,x)=-x^{s-1}e^{-x}
$$ then, by the chain rule, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d x}\left(Γ(1+d,A-c \ln x)\right)&=\frac{-c}{x}\cdot\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t} Γ(s,t)\right|_{(s,t)
=(1+d,A-c \ln x)} 
\\\\&=\frac{c}{x}\cdot(A-c \ln x)^de^{-(A-c \ln x)}
\\\\&=c\:x^{c-1}e^{-A}(A-c \ln x)^d.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure that there it is $x^c$ and not $x^{c-1}$? It would be of great assistance if you could be a bit more detailed on why this is the result. I would like to understand my fault on applying the chain rule :)

Comment: I have a question. Is $Γ_x(1+d,A-c \ln x)$ meaning $\frac{d}{dx}\left(Γ(1+d,A-c \ln x)\right)$ or is it meaning $\left.\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}Γ(1+d,t)\right)\right|_{t=A-c \ln x}$?

Comment: It is $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \Gamma(1+d,A-c\ln x) \right)$.

Comment: Ok. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: So my way of applying the chain rule is correct?

Comment: If we  read the question as finding $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \Gamma(1+d,A-c\ln x) \right)$ then *what you wrote is correct*.

Comment: Yes this type of incomplete gamma function is part of the function $g(x)=r A^{-d} e^A \Gamma(1+d,A-c\ln x)-rcx$ and I would like to find $g'(x)$. Therefore I am asking for the derivative of $\Gamma$ with respect to $x$. Is my way of thinking correct?

Comment: Ok I see, yes it is.

Comment: You are welcome!